# Listview having checkBox in custom model of PYQT

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, model-view

```
class List_Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, colors=[], parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__colors = colors

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__colors)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            value = self.__colors[row]
            return value.name()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            row = index.row()
            value = self.__colors[row]
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(26,26)
            pixmap.fill(value)
            icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
            return icon

        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            return QtCore.Qt.Checked

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    listview = QtGui.QListView()
    listview.show()

    red = QtGui.QColor(255,0,0)
    green = QtGui.QColor(0,255,0)
    blue = QtGui.QColor(0,0,255)

    model = List_Model([red, green, blue])
    listview.setModel(model)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am writing my custom List_Model model class for listview. In the data method of List_Model class I have checked the Checkstaterole for the checkboxes I want in my listview. However, I am not able to individually check and uncheck chekboxes in my custom model class.

How can I  individually check and uncheck the checkboxes?

Comment: Check the ids of all your checkboxes in QT UI. Simply, you need to identify those  individually and should be able to handle enable/disable for the checkboxes.

Comment: @Barun Sharma ... I am asking the way I can track individually... can you please share in this case of my model ...How can I do so..? In listview we have to have model....in model how can I track ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "track"? Show a realistic code example of the problem you are not able to solve.

Comment: @ekhumoro  I have added the complete code for my application and tried to make my question clearer. Please let me know in case I need to share some more details.

Comment: @Juna. I still don't really see what the problem is. If you want to save state, you need to store it somewhere - just as you are already doing with the colours. Usually, an item class is used for this, so that many pieces of information can be grouped together - but I suppose you could just use a `dict`. Are you sure you really need to write a custom model? Why can't you just use a [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html)?

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro for your good suggestion. QStandardItemModel was perfect for my implementation.